# Git renormalizing doesn't find all files that need it

Tags: git

So, I've got a large codebase that needs to have its endlines as just LF, except for one specific type of file. We ran into some problems with a Windows-based tool we use for some of our functions based on non-Windows-style line endings, so these files need to have them, and the rest should stay as is.

There's about 50 of these types of files spread across the codebase, but they all have the same naming convention, all end in "Cart.java", so a regex for "*Cart.java" should match them all.

So, I started by making sure `core.autocrlf` was set to `false`. Then I created this .gitattributes file:

`*Cart.java text eol=crlf`

At first I tried saving it in just the folder where one of these files existed, but renormalizing didn't seem to find anything. So, instead I saved it in the root folder of the repository, and when I did...

`git add --renormalize .`

...from the root directory, only one of the 50-ish files was actually found and renormalized. The rest were untouched. They're all 3 or 4 subfolders deep, so I'm at a loss as to why just the one would be found.

I'm working with git v2.31.1.windows.1. Am I missing something obvious? What else can I try?

Comment: Technically the `*Cart.java` in a `.gitattributes` line is a *glob* expression, not a regular expression. But that's a good thing because the regex for that would be `.*Cart\.java`. :-) In any case it seems like that should have matched. Consider using `git ls-files --eol` to see what attributes Git thinks apply to the various files.

Comment: Do these files differ in case from the pattern?  Git is case sensitive.

Comment: @bk2204 Case is the same for all, that pattern should always match.

Comment: @torek This is interesting.  For all the files that didn't get modified, the line from `git ls-files --eol` looks like:  

`i/lf    w/lf    attr/text eol=crlf      src/wut/ever/HerpyderpCart.java`  

But, for the one that did get modified properly, its:  

`i/lf    w/crlf  attr/text eol=crlf      src/wut/ever/ZoidbergCart.java`

Comment: OK: the i/ tells you what form the file has in the index, and the w/ tells you what form the same file has in your working tree. So the working tree copy of the one modified file already had at least one CRLF line ending in it. The others are all pure-LF-only in all respects right now, so will become "correct" (in terms of what you want) if you remove and re-extract them right now as they do have `attr/text eol=crlf`.

Comment: I'm not sure if `add --renormalize` is *supposed* to do a forced re-check-out, or not. If it is, this seems like a bug. If not ... well, the documentation may need some improving, maybe.

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a shot when I'm next able to get at this.  Seems weird that one file would get properly modified, but the rest would be left alone.  The important thing is that these files will be handled properly in the future, which is all that really matters.